# Properly Displaying Cowsay in Scala

Tags: linux, scala

If I run `cowsay Scala!` in Linux it outputs

```
 ________
< Scala! >
 --------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

If I try to display just the cow without the text bubble in Scala with this `String`

```
val cow = """
       \   ^__^
        \  (oo)\_______
           (__)\       )\/\
               ||----w |
               ||     ||"""
```

It gets displayed as

```
cow: String =
"
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
|----w |
|     ||"
```

I thought the triple quotes would escape the strings properly and not break the cows legs.

If I escape the first `|` on the legs the whitespace is correct but it now shows the escape character.

```
cow: String =
"
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                \||----w |
                \||     ||"
```

So, how do I escape this properly so it displays as the original cow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an artifact of the REPL.  It assumes you want to strip off the margin to the `|` character.  If you tried this in a regular scala file, you shouldn't see the issue unless you explicitly call `stripMargin` on the string.

To fix it in the REPL, just add `|` characters at the start of those lines, like:

```
 ________
< Scala! >
 --------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
|               ||----w |
|               ||     ||
```